# Any difference between "school-aged" and "school-age"?

Tags: difference, adjectives

I am wondering which one is correct:

1. > school-aged children
2. > school-age children

Comment: Nope. Not in real use. There may be some technical difference between them but, in general, they're used interchangeably, like "ice tea" vs "iced tea".

Comment: When speaking, it matters even less, since many (most?) accents will pronounce them identically, or with an imperceptible difference.

Comment: School-aged vs school-age Both the adjectives are correct; they can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

Either one works and they're very similar; most native speakers will probably not draw a distinction between them. "School-aged" refers to children ***aged*** to the point of attending **school** (and, implicitly, not beyond that); "school-age" refers to children *of an **age** at which* they should attend **school** (that is, neither too old nor too young).